# JavaFx failed to connect CSS file

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to connect add stylesheet 'd.css' to my scene in 'Home' class, however, they cant be found. I have no idea what my problem is and below is my code and directory. I have made sure my ID is set correct
[image]

My code:

```
> package com.example.cw;
> 
> import javafx.fxml.FXML; import javafx.fxml.Initializable; import
> javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane; import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
> import javafx.scene.text.Text;
> 
> import java.net.URL; import java.util.ResourceBundle

;

> public class Home implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    Text d;
    @FXML
    AnchorPane x;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        x.sceneProperty().addListener((observable, oldScene, newScene) -> {
            if (newScene != null) {
                newScene.getStylesheets().add(Home.class.getResource("d.css").toExternalForm()); }
        });


    }}
```

Comment: This is a strange way to configure CSS.  You can associate CSS in SceneBuilder and it will save the CSS reference in the fxml file and automatically and load and apply the css when the file is loaded.  Alternately, when you create a scene, you can set the CSS on the scene then.

Comment: @jewelsea yes sir..... but the main problem is CSS file couldn't be found

Comment: in scene builder, d.css can be found in stylesheets option, but errors still happen since d.css cant be found

Comment: “the main problem is CSS file couldn't be found” -> how do you know that when you “have no idea what my problem is”?